# How to create a submit all button for my form_for

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I am new to Ruby on Rails. How can I make my form for submit all at the same time when I click the `link_to "save"`. Thank you for your answers. This is a snippet of my view file. I would like to save form for at the same time with one button.

```
  <% @sheets.each do |getsheets| %>
      <%= image_tag "sheets/#{getsheets.sheetimage.split('/')[-2]}/#{getsheets.sheetimage.split('/')[-1]}" %>
      <div>

        <%= form_for getsheets , :url => sheet_attachment_path(getsheets.sheetid,getsheets.sheetid) do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :"Name: " %>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>

          <%= f.hidden_field :sheetid, :value => getsheets.sheetid %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :projectid, :value => getsheets.projectid %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :sheetimage, :value => getsheets.sheetimage %>

        <% end %>

        <%= link_to "Destroy Sheet", delete_sheet_path(getsheets.sheetid,params[:attachmentid]) %>

      </div>
      <br>
  <% end %>
  <div>

    <%= link_to "Save", "#"%>

    <%= link_to "Cancel",  :controller => "sheet_attachments", :action => "cancel", :attachmentid => params[:attachmentid] %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you meant by duplicate form.

Comment: my form_for is iterated at sheets.image. I want to make a single submit button for all my form_for

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need to put `<%= link_to "Save", "#"%>` in the loop, and show  form for each object.

You need to understand, that destroy button will redirect you to `index` by default, that mean that you need to stub it